# UITableView subview to uitableviewcell

Tags: uitableview, uibutton, subview

i am trying to add a button to the tableview and no matter what frame i specify the button is not visible. This is a custom UITableViewCell and I am adding the button in the code rather than in the xib file is so that I can click on the button and perform an action which is not didSelectRowAtIndexPath: 
I have the following code in cellForRowAtIndexPath: What am I missing?

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    button.frame = bframe;
    button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    return cell;
```

Comment: Please show the full code in cellForRowAtIndexPath if it's not too long.  What other controls are added to the cell that might be covering up the button?  Why not use cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton and accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath?

Comment: Thanks. I used UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton  and accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

UIButton *button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure] retain];

Comment: thanks for your reply. this doesn't work. buttonWithType does the allocation and autoRelease for you, so I don't how this is any different from what I do.